# Data fetch from Database for TransmogrifAI

Tags: python, database, transmogrifai

Could you please someone help me for fetching data directly from any MySQL Database instead of using any dataset for TransmogrifAI.
If possible can I get the code regarding this or any reference?

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a guide](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html) on how you can connect to MySQL from Apache Spark.

Once you have you Dataset / RDD materialized you can plug it into TransmogrifAI:

1. Either by automatically materializing features as shown [here](https://github.com/salesforce/TransmogrifAI/blob/master/helloworld/src/main/scala/com/salesforce/hw/titanic/OpTitanicMini.scala#L72).
2. Or you can create features manually with FeatureBuilder.fromRow function. Then construct OpWorkflow and pass the Dataset into it: `workflow. setInputDataset(data)`.

Comment: Thanks Matthew Tovbin, I have also implemented by making use of python script.
I have built connection with MySQL & fetched data.